Object Disappeared in Sculpt Mode and Edit Mode
I did one sculpting for 3 hours, and then I don't know what I pressed, but it disappeared. It is shown in Object Mode, but not in Edit Mode or Sculpt Mode, and it's not hidden either. Could anyone help me?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I know the community bot is not a real person, otherwise I would tell him it is crystal clear from the question what the issue is...

You probably mean it is not hidden in the 3D Viewport in Object Mode. But you can also hide selected faces of a mesh in Edit Mode and Sculpt Mode.
This is for example helpful if you only want to work on parts of your mesh and either not affect the other parts or keep them from obstructing your view on part you want to work on. The reason the object is still visible in Object Mode is that this is only a visual editing option, it does not affect the rendering or anything.
In Edit Mode, to hide selected parts, no matter if all or just some, you can press H, instead to keep selected parts and hide only unselected ones you can press Shift+H. If you want to unhide them press Alt+H.
In Sculpt Mode it is slightly different, usually you have no selected faces there when sculpting, in this case H always hides everything (which is what you probably did) and Alt+H unhides everything again, while Shift+H has no function.
